# How to use multithreading.Value in dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-dataclasses

Would anyone of you know if it's possible to use `multiprocessing.Value` field in `dataclass`?

For the following dataclass definition, I am getting `TypeError: this type has no size` exception.

```
import multiprocessing
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class TestResults:
    count: multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Synchronized = multiprocessing.Value(int, 0)
```

Stack trace:

```
$ python example.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 5, in <module>
    class TestResults:
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 6, in TestResults
    count: multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Synchronized = multiprocessing.Value(int, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 135, in Value
    return Value(typecode_or_type, *args, lock=lock,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 74, in Value
    obj = RawValue(typecode_or_type, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 49, in RawValue
    obj = _new_value(type_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 40, in _new_value
    size = ctypes.sizeof(type_)
TypeError: this type has no size
```

Comment: Please post the full error message including the stack trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Value` expects the first parameter as the [array](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/array.html#module-array) types, so for an int you should pass in "i" for 2 bytes or "l" for 4 bytes integer.

and as it is a mutable type you need to construct it using `field(default_factory)`.

```py
import multiprocessing
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import multiprocessing.sharedctypes

@dataclass
class TestResults:
    count: multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Synchronized = field(default_factory=lambda: multiprocessing.Value('i', 0))
```